# Post-publish events in SSDT

Tags: sql-server-data-tools

I need to execute a `PowerShell` script after I publish manually my `SSDT` project using my publishing profile (development.publish.xml).

I came across the `PostDeployEvent` target type but I couldn't make it work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I just switch to a powershell window and run the script.

Bear in mind I use the quick deploy in my ssdt dev pack to quickly deploy procs and only when I do my final run of tests do I do a full publish it makes it simpler.

Ed

Comment: I'll try to put together a PowerShell script and trigger the deployment of the database with MSBuild. Then, I'll just write the rest of the script. Does it sound like a feasible alternative? Thank you!